# automatically runs shell script at startup (Kali Linux)

Tags: boot, shell-script, bash-scripting, autorun

how can i auto run or auto start bash script after rebooting?

here is my simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 && xtrlock
```

the script basically locks my screen and mouse but not my keyboard

Comment: In Kali V2020, run Session and Startup, Application Autostart, and then you may be able to add your script lower left (ADD).

Comment: i will try. thank  you

Comment: Please let me know and I will post an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in `/etc/rc.local`.

It's executed @boot time.

If this file not exists, create it with the eXecutable bit.

Comment: thank you sir! i can just add the script or command in the rc.local?

Comment: If the file not exists, the whole script

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Note that things executed from `/etc/rc.local` will not be part of the GUI session and cannot easily affect it. A display locker would definitely need to be part of the GUI session to work as intended.